# PSQL: Combining two database tables and keep null values

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, null

I have two tables in a Postgres database. Let's call them Results1 and Results2.
They contain data on servers.

Results1 looks something like this:

```
Hostname | Name | SystemID | IPAddress | LastCheckin | OSAStatus
----------------------------------------------------------------
aaaa.com | aaaa | 0000001  | xx.xxx.x  | 20150714    | online
bbbb.com | bbbb | 0000002  | xx.xxx.y  | 20150713    | offline
cccc.com | cccc | 0000003  | xx.xxx.z  | 20150614    | online
xxxx.net | xxxx | 0000004  | xx.xxx.1  | 20130301    | unknown
```

It currently does not contain any null values, but there is always a chance that it may in the future.

The table Results2 looks something like this:

```
Hostname | Name | IPAddress | InventoryDate | Status
----------------------------------------------------------------
aaaa.com | aaaa | xx.xxx.x  | 20130714      | Retired
bbbb.com | bbbb | xx.xxx.y  |               | RunTime
cccc.com | cccc |           | 20150614      | RunTime
         | dddd | xx.xxx.a  | 20150614      | Planned
eeee.com | eeee | xx.xxx.b  |               | Installation
ffff.com | ffff | xx.xxx.c  |               | Retired
gggg.com | gggg | xx.xxx.d  | 20150614      | RunTime
```

What I want to do is to combine/join these two tables so that I can compare the data. 
I want to join them on Name, as this is the only common value in the tables which can not be empty.

I have tried the following SELECT statement:

```
SELECT Results1.Name, SystemID, LastCheckin, InventoryDate, OSAStatus, Status AS R1Status
FROM Results1
FULL OUTER JOIN
Results2 
ON Results1.Name=Results2.Name
ORDER BY Name;
```

It partly does what I want, but not completely. The results I get is something like this:

```
Name | SystemID | LastCheckin | InventoryDate | OSAStatus | R1Status
----------------------------------------------------------------
aaaa | 0000001  | 20130714    | 20130714      |  online   | Retired
bbbb | 0000002  | 20150713    |               |  offline  | RunTime
cccc | 0000003  | 20150614    | 20150616      |  online   | RunTime
xxxx | 0000004  | 20130301    |               |  unknown  |
     |          |             |               |           | Planned
     |          |             |               |           | Installation
     |          |             |               |           | Retired
     |          |             | 20150614      |           | RunTime
```

As you can see. When a server only exists in Results2 and not in Results1, I loose the Name attribute for that server, which is a big issue. 
When a server exists in both Results1 and Results2, or only in Results1, it works as I want it too.

I know that I only select Results1.Name, but I don't know how to handle them both without having them end up in different columns.

Could anyone help me with a PSQL query which is able to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` does what you want:

```
SELECT r1.Name, SystemID, LastCheckin, InventoryDate, OSAStatus, Status AS R1Status
FROM Results1 r1 FULL OUTER JOIN
     Results2 r2
     ON r1.Name IS NOT DISTINCT FROM r2.Name
ORDER BY Name;
```

You might also want to select `COALESCE(r1.Name, r2.Name) as Name` instead of just `r1.Name`.

Comment: COALESCE(r1.Name, r2.Name) as Name 
Worked great! Thank you. Verified it and all the data is intact and working like it should! I will accept your answer :)

DISTINCT however does not seem valid for PSQL?

Comment: @Ambrose . . . `distinct` works fine in Postgres.  If you have a question about that, then ask another question.